# Kubernetes How to confirm DNS is working

Tags: dns, kubernetes

I have successfully created a Kubernetes POD/Service using MiniKube on windows. But I would now like to ensure that DNS is working correctly.

The DNS service is shown as running

```
.\kubectl get pod -n kube-system
```

Which shows me the kube-dns pod is running

[image]

I also have the DNS add on shown as running

[image]

So I then want to verify that DNS is working, Ideally I want to test that PODs that have a service on top of them can lookup the service by DNS name.

But I started simple like this, where I get my running POD

[image]

So now that I have my POD name, I want to try do simple DNS lookup in it using the following commmand

```
.\kubectl exec simple-sswebapi-pod-v1-f7f8764b9-xs822 -- nslookup google.com
```

Where I am using the **kubectl  exec** to try and run this nslookup in the POD that was found (running I should point out above).

But I get this error

[image]

Why would it not be able to find **nslookup** inside POD. All the key things seem to be ok

- Kube-DNS pod is running (as shown above)
- DNS AddOn is installed and running (as shown above)

What am I missing, is there something else I need to enable for DNS lookups to work inside my PODs?

Comment: You do not have nslookup tool inside the pod (your image doesn't have it). Execute a shell inside the pod and install nslookup and then try again.

Comment: does that mean the shell command needs to be part of my initial docker image. Or can I do that now? If so any chance of an example. I am new to this. Guess this is why most examples I have seen of DNS lookup use busybox which comes with nslookup

Comment: Think what I will do is create a new service/POD that uses busy box just to check the DNS lookup stuff. Thanks again for your answer. You should promote your comment here to full answer, then I can vote you up

Comment: @tselvan I added another part to this question, any ideas on this new query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it like this your container needs to include the command you want to use inside of the built image.

Sidenote: `kubectl debug` is coming to kube in near future https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45922 which will help solve things like that by enabling you to attach a custom container to existing pod and debug in it

Comment: Ok think I get you. @tselvan also said the same.

Comment: I added another part to this question, any ideas on this new query?

Answer (score 1):

So more on this I installed busybox into a POD to allow me to use nslookup and this enabled me to do this

[image]

So this looks cool, but should I not be able to ping that service either by its IP address or by its DNS name which seems to be resolving just fine as shown above.

If I **ping google.com** inside busybox command prompt all is ok, but when I do a ping for either this IP address of this service of the DNS names, it never gets anywhere.

DNS lookup is clearly working. What am I missing?

Comment: For ping to work, the service should be listening to ICMP requests. https://superuser.com/questions/549617/no-reply-for-ping-command-what-does-this-mean

Comment: And the reason k8s service are not listening on ICMP requests are basically because they don't have iptables rules for the same. Read the last part here: http://leebriggs.co.uk/blog/2017/02/15/kubernetes-networking-part1.html

Comment: Again thanks, I'm a dev so this is not day job. But I kind of enjoy it, thanks so much for the answers