# K8s service not pingable

Tags: kubernetes, ping, minikube, nslookup, coredns

I have a k8s service/deployment in a minikube cluster (name `amq` in `default` namespace:

```
D20181472:argo-k8s gms$ kubectl get svc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
argo          argo-ui      ClusterIP      10.97.242.57     <none>        80/TCP            5h19m
default       amq          LoadBalancer   10.102.205.126   <pending>     61616:32514/TCP   4m4s
default       kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP           5h23m
kube-system   kube-dns     ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP     5h23m
```

I spun up infoblox/dnstools, and tried `nslookup`, `dig` and `ping` of `amq.default` with the following results:

```
dnstools# nslookup amq.default
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   amq.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.102.205.126

dnstools# ping amq.default
PING amq.default (10.102.205.126): 56 data bytes
^C
--- amq.default ping statistics ---
28 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
dnstools# dig amq.default

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3 <<>> amq.default
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 15104
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;amq.default.           IN  A

;; Query time: 32 msec
;; SERVER: 10.96.0.10#53(10.96.0.10)
;; WHEN: Sat Jan 26 01:58:13 UTC 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 29

dnstools# ping amq.default
PING amq.default (10.102.205.126): 56 data bytes
^C
--- amq.default ping statistics ---
897 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

(NB: pinging the ip address directly gives the same result)

I admittedly am not very knowledgable about the deep workings of DNS, so I am not sure why I can do a lookup and dig for the hostname, but not ping it.

Comment: [For ping to work, the service should be listening to ICMP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025825/kubernetes-how-to-confirm-dns-is-working)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I admittedly am not very knowledgable about the deep workings of DNS, so I am not sure why I can do a lookup and dig for the hostname, but not ping it.

Because `Service` IP addresses are figments of your cluster's imagination, caused by either iptables or ipvs, and don't actually exist. You can see them with `iptables -t nat -L -n` on any Node that is running `kube-proxy` (or `ipvsadm -ln`), as is described by the helpful [Debug[-ing] Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#iptables) page

Since they are not real IPs bound to actual NICs, they don't respond to any traffic other than the port numbers registered in the `Service` resource. The correct way of testing connectivity against a service is with something like `curl` or `netcat` and using the port number upon which you are expecting application traffic to travel.

Comment: Thanks. Testing against a port is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

That’s because the service’s cluster IP is a virtual IP, and only has meaning when combined with the service port.

Whenever a service gets created by API server a Virtual IP address is assigned to it immediately and after that, the API server notifies all kube-proxy agents running on the worker nodes that a new Service has been created. Then, It's kube-proxy's job to make that service addressable on the node it’s running on. kube-proxy does this by setting up a few iptables rules, which make sure each packet destined for the service IP/port pair is intercepted and its destination address modified, so the packet is redirected to one of the pods backing the service.

[IPs and VIPs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#ips-and-vips)